# php: Run a python script from php

Tags: php, python, exec, shell-exec

i just wanted to ask you how i can run my **python** script **from php**!
I tried shell_exec, exec, system and passthru - noting happened.

www-data has sudo acces (sudoers).

If i do it with `sudo su www-data` i can run the script.

Thats confusing to me.

My script looks like this:

```
echo '<pre>';
echo $output = shell_exec('/usr/bin/python /var/www/inc/send.py');
echo '</pre>';
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are not echoing `$output`. What is its value?

Comment: `$output` is empty. There's no output. If i do it with `ls -al` for example i get an output.

Comment: Does your command generate output? You seem to be sending everything to `/dev/null`...

Comment: It should generate an error output because there are no argv set.

Answer (score 0):

In which directory do you have your send.py script? Try to add full path to send.py and print (echo) output.

Comment: Okay i added the full path to my script and the print -> nothing changed. Still no output.